# Spring Integration TcpInboundGateway sending conditional reply

Tags: spring-integration

I have configured `TcpInboundGateway` to receive requests from client and my configuration is as follows. So as per below configuration every client requested is responded back,but what i want is response should be send back only if certain condition is true,not the every time, what changes needs to be done in configuration?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class SpringIntegrationApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(SpringIntegrationApplication.class, args);       
        System.in.read();
        ctx.close();
    }


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringIntegrationApplication.class);
    }

    private static Class<SpringIntegrationApplication> applicationClass = SpringIntegrationApplication.class;


    @Bean
    TcpNetServerConnectionFactory cf(){
        TcpNetServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory=new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(8765);

        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    TcpInboundGateway tcpGate(){

        TcpInboundGateway gateway=new TcpInboundGateway();
        gateway.setConnectionFactory(cf());
        gateway.setRequestChannel(requestChannel());
        return gateway;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel requestChannel(){

        return new DirectChannel();
    }


    @MessageEndpoint 
    public class Echo {

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="requestChannel")
    public byte[] echo(byte[] in,@SuppressWarnings("deprecation") @Header("ip_address") String ip){

        byte[] rawbytes = gosDataSerivce.byteArrayToHex(in,ip);//Process bytes and returns result

        return rawbytes;    

    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where is your problem, but you can just simply return `null` from your `echo()`. In that case the `ServiceActivatingHandler` doesn't care and stops it work. Just because of `requiresReply = false`.

From other side the `TcpInboundGateway` doesn't care about `null`, too:

```
Message<?> reply = this.sendAndReceiveMessage(message);
if (reply == null) {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("null reply received for " + message + " nothing to send");
    }
    return false;
}
```

That is possible because of `replyTimeout` option for the `MessagingTemplate` on the background. By default it is `1 sec`. After that the `sendAndReceiveMessage()` just returns `null` to the caller.

You can adjust this option on the `TcpInboundGateway`.

Comment: If you have no async handoffs, you can safely set the reply timeout to 0 - the clock doesn't start until the thread returns to the gateway. You can also use [Collaborating Channel Adapters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#_collaborating_outbound_and_inbound_channel_adapters) instead of a gateway for arbitrary messaging.

Comment: my use case is of request/reply ,non-blocking and should have multi-threading support can this be achieved using Collaboration Channel Adapters